# Using Spring @Autowired with Scala Trait

Tags: spring, scala, dependency-injection

I have a simple scenario where I extend a Scala trait as follows:

```
    trait Vehicle {

      @Autowired
      private var myDistanceLogger: MyDistanceLogger = null

      def travel(miles:Int) = {
        println("travelling " + miles)
        myDistanceLogger.logMiles(miles)
      }
    }

    @Component
    class Truck extends Vehicle {

    }
```

Even though the Truck package is in Springs component-scan, I am getting a nullpointer exception. All other (non-extended) classes in the package are wired up fine. Any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little speculation - traits in scala gets translated to a java interface, based on [this](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala) article. 
So, your trait:

```
trait Vehicle {
      @Autowired
      private var myDistanceLogger: MyDistanceLogger = null
}
```

would get translated to:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    public MyDistanceLogger myDistanceLogger();
}
```

and `@Autowired` would not make sense in a getter, I am guessing this is the reason why this does not get autowired.

Comment: Ok, interesting, thanks. Actually my class is a Scala Steps class for Cucumber testing. Now I am extending a class rather than a trait and the DI is working.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it does work - the private var in the trait gets autowired correctly.

When are you calling travel()?   That is, are you calling it for sure after all the Spring initialization is complete?

Comment: As stated above my class i.e. Truck class is a Cucumber Steps file. I am using Cucumber in my RunWith annotation which does not provide the same level of Spring support as SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. For instance, my once working Resource annotated beans are no longer available for wiring, so I am using Autowired instead. Im guessing this is yet another limitation of the Cucumber test runner.

Answer (score 0):

Scala places the annotation on the field, where Spring won't find it. You need to ensure that it is placed on the Scala's internal setter method:

```
import scala.annotation.meta.setter

@(Autowired @setter)
private var myDistanceLogger: MyDistanceLogger = _
```